# Load all fragments at once (including fragments which are inside fragments)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So this is my main activity class

```
public class NewMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_main_activity);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.purple_500));

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        //NewNav
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navView);
        navigationView.bringToFront();
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.mm_home);
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;

                        case R.id.nav_faq:
                            selectedFragment = new FAQFragment();
                            break;

                        case R.id.nav_price:
                            selectedFragment = new PriceMarketFragment();
                            break;

                        case R.id.nav_news:
                            selectedFragment = new NewsFragment();
                            break;
                    }

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();

                    return true;
                }

            };
```

I have a frame layout in my mainactivity xml which i have given ID fragment_container.

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navBottom"/>
```

In bottom navigation, I have 4 fragments, in which 3 fragments (Home, Price and News), I have tablayouts (more fragments within fragments).

When the mainactivity starts (the application starts) i want all of the parent fragments and child fragments to be loaded. and then i only need to navigate through them.

How can i do this please help.

Comment: you can simply avoid creating new instances of these fragments in the `onNavigationItemSelected` & initialize them in the `onCreate` & assign them to variables.

Comment: @DarShan can you please show me a demo like how to do it.

Comment: Declare a variable like `private lateinit var homeFragment: HomeFragment` then initialize it in your `onCreate` like `homeFragment = HomeFragment()`, use this variable in your `onNavigationItemSelected`.

Comment: @DarShan But there is an error then, fragment already created while using .add.

Comment: try using `replace`

Comment: replace is destroying it. As I open price market fragment, it takes load, but when i go to another fragment and comes back to it. It again starts taking load.

Comment: You can use a `ViewPager` then.